# Meteor-angular ng-upload doesn't work properly. tutorial step 20 issue

Tags: meteor, angular-meteor

I followed tutorial on meteor-angular and when I reached step 20, I found out that there is something wrong with file upload area.
Sometimes when I click it, it doesn't open upload window - sometimes it takes even 3 or 4 clicks before input work. I checked live demo of step 20, and input is bugged there aswell.

Code i'm using for tests is:

```js
var app = angular.module('fileUpload', ['ngFileUpload', 'ngRoute']);

app.controller("AddPhotoCtrl", function($scope) {



});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.1/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src = "http://angular-file-upload.appspot.com/js/ng-file-upload.js">
</script>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0rc1/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://angular-file-upload.appspot.com/js/ng-file-upload-shim.js"></script>
<div ng-app="fileUpload" ng-controller="AddPhotoCtrl">
  <div ngf-drop ngf-select ngf-change="addImages($files)" ngf-drag-over-class="{accept:'dragover', reject:'dragover-err', delay:100}" class="drop-box" ngf-multiple="false" ngf-allow-dir="true" ngf-accept="'image/*'" ngf-drop-available="dropAvailable">
    <button>Click here to select image</button>
    <div>
      <strong>OR</strong>
    </div>
    <div ng-show="dropAvailable">You can also drop image to here</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I made quick reproduction example: http://ngupload.meteor.com

I think It must be meteor related because same code on http://jsfiddle.net/s8kc7wg0/282/ works fine.

Console does not show anything, inspecting element blinks on clicking it when it doesn't ignite, but nothing changes.

Please help me solve this.

Comment: tested on chrome and opera

Comment: checked firefox - looks alright

Comment: Sooo what are you talking about?? Works every time on Chrome, FF, Safari

Comment: Checked on 2 more workstations.. same thing appears, file select window appears on second or third click...

Comment: I cannot reproduce this on my Mac

Comment: try doubleclicking anywhere outside div, and then click on button. there is 95% chance that nothing will happen, at least on windows opera and chrome browsers

Comment: I can tripleclick outside of the div, but still cannot reproduce this on mentioned browsers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like meteor package for ng-file upload is terribly outdated. I found workaround and placed ng-upload into client/lib folder - I just wonder why meteor tells us to use outdated packets, while such simple solution works..